# Stop cellForRowAtIndexPath from being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a table view in my app where the cells contain only one textview per cell. These textviews are populated with text stored in the NSUserDefaults. The user can change the text and than it is saved again. The text array(the text which is used to populate the textviews) from NSUserDefaults is loaded at `viewDidLoad`. However, the text of the textviews in the cells are set in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. The problem is that `cellForRowAtIndexPath`is called when ever the user scrolls the tableview so if he/she is editing one of the textViews and scrolls while still typing, everything disappears because `cellForRowAtIndexPath`is called and the textViews text's are set from the saved data which was loaded on `viewDidLoad`.

So..I figured maybe letting `cellForRowAtIndexPath` change the text of textviews only once(at app start) will solve the problem but as it turns out `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called individually for every cell. So it was working but only loaded the text for the first cell's textView because I only let `cellForRowAtIndexPath` do that once.

**My question is:** How can I let `cellForRowAtIndexPath` change the textView's texts of all the cells only when viewDidLoad is called as well?  Or can I set the textView's text for each cell from the `viewDidLoad` method? As that would clearly solve the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand fully how `UITableView` works. `-cellForRowAtIndexPath` is supposed to be called each time the table needs a new cell (which is typical as you scroll). Also, are you certain `-cellForRowAtIndexPath` is being called before `-viewDidLoad`? That doesn't sound right.

Comment: True, I tested it out and `viewDidLoad` is called before `-cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Any suggestions how I could over come this issue though?

Comment: You need to save the changed data, in your `UITableViewCell` somehow. You can place it in an array and store it in memory, or if you need to save it down for future sessions, you could save it to CoreData. Regarding `viewDidLoad`, I suggest you review the view lifecycle docs that Apple provides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever the user changes text in the textview in one of your cells - save that text immediately to your textArray. Now if user scrolls away, and then returns to that cell - the cell will contain the updated text. Then when the user finishes editing the text in this screen, save all changes to NSUserDefaults (for example, you can save it in viewWillDisappear).